# Preserve output color when running exec command

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, colors, terminal

If you run a command `npm command` you get a colored output like this.

[image]

However if I run the command through a node module, like this.

```
var execSync = require('child_process').execSync
execSync('npm substack')
```

The color is lost.

[image]

Is there any way to preserve the color when the cmd runs within the node file?

Not sure how node-specific this question is. Here's a generic echo that outputs `--> Starting program.` where the arrow is green.

```
echo -e "\\033[38;5;2m-->\\033[0m Starting program."
```

What I need is a command that will convert this output back to this string above.

Comment: What is `npm command` - some sort of shell built-in command? *Most likely* this shell checks if the output is a terminal, and only outputs ANSI escaped color codes if so. I use that trick in my own programs, with [`isatty`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) to set a flag if colors should be inserted.

Comment: @Jongware `npm` is a shell command. How can I fake the command to thinking that theres a shell, so it will print it's output with color?

Comment: I believe that the output of the code is in `utf8` and the string just gets logged as-is. I need a way to output the ansi string from the command rather then the colorized string.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The command [`npm config set color always`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#color) will ensure that the color is always outputted.